# PCL 1.6 with OpenCV in MS VC++ 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, computer-vision, point-cloud-library

I am trying to integrate PCl with opencv using MS VC++ 2010. I followed the procedure mentioned http://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/06/28/integrating-pcl-and-opencv-passthrough-filter-example/ here. Solution was created successfully and was built with a message 2 successful and 1 skipped.

but when I try to run it, I get an error saying Unable to start program C:/project/build/Debug/ALL_BUILD, what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably have to select the project you want to run first, and make it the 'startup project'

ALL_BUILD does not contain any runnable code